# Managing a Reactive Form value and the value is an object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have an Array I'm getting from the server, which contains Objects like this:

```
[
    {LanguageName: 'English', ID : 2},
    {LanguageName: 'Dutch', ID : 1},
    {LanguageName: 'portuguese', ID: 3},

]
```

I'm handling this by by creating a Form-Array.

My Issue:
I want that if the user changes this input, it will change only the property of the Name, something like: anyFormName.controls.value.LanguageName, and not replacing the whole value altogether to a string, so insted of end up getting :

```
    anyFormName.controls.value = "User's Input"
```

, I'll get:

```
anyFormName.controls.value = {LanguageName: "User's Input", ID : 2}
```

I've worked around this issue before with setValue() to the specific control, and saving the data  in another array so I can compare the position by the indexes of the form Array. seems to me there probably be a better way...

thanks a lot!

Comment: what does mean of this statement "not replacing the whole value altogether to a string" ? please elaborate

Comment: At first, I'm using the setValue() method to put the value from the server inside the control's value, so it will be like: control.value = {LanguageName : 'somthing', ID: 2}.But when the user changes the value of the input field, insted of getting this: value = {LanguageName : 'somthing new', ID: 2}, I'll get value = "somhting new"

Comment: then where is the problem? Sorry, but I am not getting you. please explain.

Comment: Basicly when a user enters its input, im losing the original object, and left only with the input itself as a string. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal, in general you'll get a formArray like

```
<div *ngIf="myFormArray" [formGroup]="myFormArray">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myFormArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="ID">
    <input formControlName="LanguageName">
  </div>
</div>
{{myFormArray?.value|json}}
```

//Or

```
<div *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="data">
    <div *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('data').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="ID">
      <input formControlName="LanguageName">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{myForm?.value|json}}
```

where you has some like

```
myForm:FormGroup
myFormArray:FormArray;

values=[
   {LanguageName: 'English', ID : 2},
   {LanguageName: 'Dutch', ID : 1},
   {LanguageName: 'portuguese', ID: 3},
]
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm=this.fb.group({
        data:this.fb.array(this.createFormArray(this.values))
    })
    this.myFormArray=this.fb.array(this.createFormArray(this.values));
}
createFormArray(values:any):FormGroup[]
{
    return values.map(x=>{
        return this.fb.group(
            {
                LanguageName:x.LanguageName,
                ID:x.ID
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Just not include the input formControlName="ID"

Comment: Thank very much! it seems to be the right way for me.

Comment: im geeting this error though:     Cannot find control with path: 'FieldNames -> 0 (and all the length of the array...) ->

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you when say "FieldNames". I make a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foxfmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand you properly, you're trying to change the form control name instead of its value. That can be accomplished by this method:

```
changeFormFieldName(oldField: string, newField: string): void {

  var newControls: {[key: string]: FormControl} = {};
  Object.keys(this.form.controls).map((field: string) => {
    if (field==oldField) {
      newControls[newField] = this.form.controls[field];
    } else {
      newControls[field] = this.form.controls[field];
    }
  });

  this.form = new FormGroup(newControls);

}
```

*assuming your form group object is under `this.form`*.